# Jmeter: junit request is not giving results

Tags: junit, jmeter, performance-testing

I am using junit request in jmeter to get the performance result of the scripts. When I run the script it is not giving any error however it is not giving the results.
I am adding the jav source code of junit request and also will provide the output screen.
please check what is the issue as i have added the required plugins and jar into the same

```js
package com.seleniummaster.jmeterjunit;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;


public class LoginTest {
  private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();  
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //use Firefox driver
//    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //use demo.mahara.org site for testing
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
    "D:\\Seleniumdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new MarionetteDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      baseUrl = "http://demo.mahara.org";
      //timeout if site page does not load in 30 seconds
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //quit the test
    driver.quit();
      String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
      if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
      }
  }
  @Test
  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    //navigate to base url
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    //clear username filed
      driver.findElement(By.id("login_login_username")).clear();
      //enter user name
      driver.findElement(By.id("login_login_username")).sendKeys("student1");
      //clear password
      driver.findElement(By.id("login_login_password")).clear();
      //enter password
      driver.findElement(By.id("login_login_password")).sendKeys("Testing1");
      //click on submit button
      driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit")).click();
      //assert the Dashboard link text
      for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.linkText("Dashboard"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }

      assertEquals("Dashboard", driver.findElement(By.linkText("Dashboard")).getText());
    }
  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
      try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
      } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    private boolean isAlertPresent() {
      try {
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        return true;
      } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
      try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        if (acceptNextAlert) {
          alert.accept();
        } else {
          alert.dismiss();
        }
        return alertText;
      } finally {
        acceptNextAlert = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this issue as the script is not producing the output

Comment: issue is still exist so please let me know if any solution is available

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue. I checked below two boxes in the Junit Request page on Jmeter UI.

- Append assertion errors
- Append runtime exception

After this when I executed the test again, I found the error in the "View Results Tree" listener under Response Message field.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try making all private variables as public. It may happen that JMeter is not able access those.

Also, refer console on JMeter, it should show you errors/exceptions.

[image]